# Ansible not overriding default vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have the following variables defined in `role/defaults/main.yml`:

```
jvm_heap_size_max: 1024
jvm_heap_size_min: "{{ (jvm_heap_size_max * 0.5)|int|abs }}"
```

My `group_vars` folder looks like this:

```
├── group_vars
│   ├── all
│   ├── group
│   │   ├── vars
│   │   └── vault
```

And I have the following variable in `inventories/test/group_vars/group/vars`:

```
jvm_heap_size_max: 512
jvm_heap_size_min: 1024
```

My expected output is:

```
jvm_heap_size_max: 512
jvm_heap_size_min: 1024
```

But what I'm getting is this:

```
jvm_heap_size_max: 1024
jvm_heap_size_min: 1024
```

How come? I'm using Ansible 2.7.7

Comment: `min` is greater than `max` in your example. Does not preclude an answer, but is still confusing. Is it intended?

Comment: It's just to illustrate that the value has changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to mention that I'm targeting the same host in my example above. Apparently, this behavior is documented:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-variables-are-merged

> By default variables are merged/flattened to the specific host before a play is run. This keeps Ansible focused on the Host and Task, so groups don’t really survive outside of inventory and host matching. By default, Ansible overwrites variables including the ones defined for a group and/or host (see the hash_merge setting to change this) .

Answer (score 2):

This should work as you described.

I set up a minimal example, and verified that `group_vars` do have higher precedence than role defaults, as is [written in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

As your example does not include the actual name of the group, and the respective folder names, I assume that is where the error lies.

Also, when I verified this, my `group_vars` were in the file `group_vars/all.yml` in the root directory of my project, I am not familiar with the other pattern.

Quick example using `localhost` and `group_vars/all.yml`:

**`roles/testrole/defaults/main.yml`**

```
---
jvm_heap_size_max: 1024
jvm_heap_size_min: "{{ (jvm_heap_size_max * 0.5)|int|abs }}"
```

**`roles/testrole/tasks/main.yml`**

```
---
- debug:
    var: jvm_heap_size_min

- debug:
    var: jvm_heap_size_max
```

**`group_vars/all.yml`**

```
---
jvm_heap_size_max: 2048
```

**`testplay.yml`**

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - testrole
```

**Invocation & output:**

```
➜  ansible-playbook testplay.yml
 [WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/hosts as an inventory source

 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [testrole : debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "jvm_heap_size_min": "1024"
}

TASK [testrole : debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "jvm_heap_size_max": 2048
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Using `group_vars/all.yml` works but doesn't seem to work if it's in `group_vars/group/vars`

Comment: As I wrote, I am not familiar with that directory layout pattern you mention. I would use `group_vars/my-group.yml`.

Comment: @Francis Has this solved your problem? Please accept the answer if it did, thank you!